# adding a prototype property by Object.defineProperty override the constructor property

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Test(){
this.time='pat';
}

Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'time', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () { return 'test'; }
});

var a=new Test();

console.log(a.time); //test
```

why a.time return value is 'test',I'm so confused with it.

Answer (score 3):

Since `time` is not a simple property, an assignment to it uses the property definition on the prototype. Since the property on the prototype is defined with a *getter* but not *setter*, it cannot be assigned to. If you were in strict mode (generally a good idea), you'd get an error about it.

The constructor *can* create an "own" `time` property on the instance, just not with simple assignment; it has to use `defineProperty` to do it:

```js
function Test(){
  Object.defineProperty(this, "time", {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: 'pat'
  });
}

Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'time', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () { return 'test'; }
});

var a=new Test();
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("time")); // true
console.log(a.time); //pat
a.time = "updated";
console.log(a.time); //updated
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what you defined your `get` method to return. Whatever value you have the function in `get` return is the value it resolves to.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'time', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () { return 'A new value!'; }
});

var a = new Test();

console.log(a.time); //A new value!
```

If you're wondering why the console.log outputs the new value as opposed to the one originally defined, well, that's because you set `Object.defineProperty` to reconfigure `Test.prototype.time` to be a new value which made new instance of it also a new value.

You could test this for yourself:

```
function Test(){
  this.time='pat';
}

// This instance will have the old values
var b = new Test();

// Change value returned by Test.time by new Test instances
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'time', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () { return 'A new value!'; }
});

var a = new Test();

console.log(a.time); // A new value!
consoel.log(b.time); // pat
```

When you instantiated `b` you gave you made an instance with the original definitions. However, when you instantialized `a` you made an instance with the new definitions of `time` which is why it's different.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know why the value on the object itself wasn't returned first before checking the prototype.